# Executing two PDO statements in one loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have a for loop for a PDO statement and I'd like it to do two things.  Data is received from the user device in an array of arrays called $data.  I'd like to insert each row into a table called 'theJack'.  This part works fine.

I then would like another statement to check the [userName] and [id] from the $data table and update a column ([Synched] values 'Y' or  'N') in theJack where [userName] and [id] match in both tables.  So far I have this (just testing with [userName] for now):

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($data); ++$i) {  

    $row = $data[$i];
    $userName = $row[userName];

    $STH = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO theJack (id, phoneID, userName, noDeer, Lat, Lon, Acc, Time, Synched) value (:id, :UUID, :userName, :noDeer, :lat, :lng, :accuracy, :timestamp, :synched)");
    $UPD = $conn->prepare("UPDATE theJack SET Synched = 'Y' WHERE userName= :userName");
    $UPD->bindParam(':userName', $userName);

    $STH->execute($row);
    $UPD->execute($row);
}
```

$row is each row from the input $data array.  $row[userName] is the userName in that row.  $STH is the INSERT statement and $UPD is the UPDATE statement.

So far, the INSERT statement works fine on its own.  Adding the UPDATE statement also works until I try to add the WHERE clause.

Just to add, I get a number of bound variables does not match number of tokens error.

Comment: are you binding your insert query anywhere?

Comment: No I'm not binding the insert query. As I said, the INSERT query seems fine (without binding).  If I try to bind elsewhere will that affect it?  Plus, I'll be binding the INSERT when in production to avoid SQL injection.  At present it's not bound anywhere.

Comment: right... also, can I assume that you've got more code you aren't showing us which would justify you running an update query affecting the line you've just inserted? (as opposed to inserting `Synched = 'Y'` to start with?

Comment: @scrowler thanks for the help.  In answer to your question, the original data comes from the user's device.  When uploaded to the remote database I want the [synched] value to switch from N to Y to signify success in uploading.  I can then report back to the user which transfers were successful and which were not.  The unsuccessful ones to be attempted again.  Make sense?  the $UPD->execute(); answer below works.  Just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another silly typo question.

```
$UPD->execute();
```